# Filter Dictionary using key and Value in list in Python

Tags: dictionary

I am new to python and trying to filter a dictionary from list using  value and key. I am using python 3

```
[{'ctime': 1459426422, 'accesskey': 'xxxxxx', 'secretkey': 'xxxx', 'id': 4, 'fsname': '/mnt/cdrom1', 'name': '/mnt/cdrom1:test1'}, {'ctime': 1459326975, 'accesskey': 'xxxx', 'secretkey': 'xxxx', 'id': 1, 'fsname': '/mnt/cdrom2', 'name': '/mnt/cdrom2:test2'}]
```

From above output, I need to filter a dictionary with key value as 'name':'/mnt/cdrom2:test2' so I get fitered dictionary as

```
{'ctime': 1459326975, 'accesskey': 'xxxx', 'secretkey': 'xxxx', 'id': 1, 'fsname': '/mnt/cdrom2', 'name': '/mnt/cdrom2:test2'}
```

I can then later extract  keys and values as needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your above list is in a variable named "my_list"

Python 2.7.x Version

```
for d in my_list:
    if d['name'] == '/mnt/cdrom2:test2':
        print d['name'] # or do whatever you want here
```

Python 3 Version

```
for d in my_list:
    if d['name'] == '/mnt/cdrom2:test2':
        print(d['name']) # or do whatever you want here
```